# DIV folding/unfolding with javascript when clicking on navigation menu links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently, the code below unfolds the DIVs every time the user clicks on a menu item (if he clicks several time on the same link it will fold and unfold the same number of times, but it never stays folded/closed).

What I would like is that when the user clicks a second time on the same menu item link, the DIV gets folded and stays like this. Like on this website

**Edit:** I realize the above might not be clear, so to summarize :

*Current process:*

- One click on a navigation menu link opens (unfolds) the associated
  DIV
- One more click on the same navigation link hides (folds) the DIV
  then reopens it automatically

*Desired new process:*

- One click on a navigation menu link opens (unfolds) the associated
  DIV
- One more click on the same navigation link hides (folds) the DIV
  and that's it. The DIV stays folded until the user clicks again on the same link, or on another menu items.

How could I achieve that? Many thanks

See http://jsfiddle.net/u3qtt6fo/5/

JS:

```
$("a").click(function() { 
    var page = $(this).data("page");
    var active = $(".fold.active");

    // if there is visible fold element on page (user already clicked at least once on link)
    if(active.length) {
      $(".fold.active")
      .animate({ width: "0" }, 200 )
      .animate({ height: "0" }, 200, function() {
      // this happens after above animations are complete
        $(this).removeClass("active")

        $("#"+page)
        .addClass("active")
        .animate({ height: "500px" }, 1000, 'linear' )
        .animate({ width: "500px" }, 400,'linear' )    


      })

    // clicking for the first time
    } else {  
      $("#"+page)
      .addClass("active")
      .animate({ height: "500px" }, 1000,'linear' )
      .animate({ width: "500px" }, 400,'linear' )

    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="fold1" class="fold">Div menu item 1</div>
<div id="fold2" class="fold">Div menu item 2</div>
<div id="fold3" class="fold">Div menu item 3</div>
<div id="fold4" class="fold">Div menu item 4</div>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-page="fold1">Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-page="fold2">Menu item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-page="fold3">Menu item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-page="fold4">Menu item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.fold {
    display: none;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.fold.active {
    display: inline-block;
}

#fold1 {
    border: solid 5px #bada55;
    background: red;
}

#fold2 {
    border: solid 5px #fed900;
    background: aqua;
}

#fold3 {
    border: solid 5px #223322;
    background: green;
}

#fold4 {
    border: solid 5px #55bada;
    background: purple;
}

ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you need ? http://jsfiddle.net/u3qtt6fo/11/

I edited your code a little, I added jQuery selector "animated"

```
$("a").click(function () {
    var page = $(this).data("page");
    if ($('div:animated').id != page) {
        var active = $(".fold.active");

        // if there is visible fold element on page (user already clicked at least once on link)
        if (active.length) {
            active.animate({
            width: "0"
            }, 200)
                .animate({
                height: "0"
            }, 200, function () {
                // this happens after above animations are complete
                $(this).removeClass("active");
            })
        // clicking for the first time
        } else {
            $("#" + page)
                .addClass("active")
                .animate({
                height: "500px"
            }, 1000, 'linear')
                .animate({
                width: "500px"
            }, 400, 'linear')
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Almost. But with your code when the user clicks several times on a menu item the DIV folds then unfolds automatically. What I would like is that if he clicks 1x then the DIV unfolds (= is visible), and if he clicks 1x again the DIV folds and stays folded (by folded I mean closed/invisible). Like the website I took as an example in my post.Many thanks

Comment: Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/rnjea41y/ I changed the "else" clause to an "if" which checks, if a new link is clicked, the new div will be displayed. Also I added "position:absolute" to the CSS of .fold